# Oracle 18c external table importing csv file from UNC path

Tags: oracle, csv, directory, unc, external-tables

> ### Preface
>
> This script has worked previously when importing a csv file into an external table when using a **local path** for the created directory (with a local drive like F:\stats) **instead** of a UNC path (\\station-1\...)

### Script

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY csvdir AS '\\Station-1\mainFolder\stats';

DROP TABLE EXT_index;
CREATE TABLE EXT_index(
  SESSION_STATION NVARCHAR2(60),
  "user" NVARCHAR2(20),
  "type" NCHAR(4),
  "date" DATE,
  "hour" NVARCHAR2(8),
  BATCH NUMBER,
  STEP NUMBER,
  VARIANTE NUMBER,
  TIME_MS NUMBER,
  NB_FOLDER NUMBER,
  NB_DOC NUMBER,
  NB_FIELDS NUMBER,
  NB_FIELDS_SHOW NUMBER,
  NB_FIELDS_CONFIRM NUMBER,
  NB_FIELDS_EMPTY NUMBER,
  NB_KEY NUMBER,
  NB_CHAR NUMBER,
  NB_USEFUL_CHAR NUMBER
)organization external (
  type oracle_loader 
  default directory csvdir 
  access parameters (
    records delimited by newline skip 1 
    fields terminated by ';' lrtrim 
    missing field values are null (
      SESSION_STATION,
      "user",
      "type",
      "date" date 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      "hour",
      BATCH,
      STEP,
      VARIANTE,
      TIME_MS,
      NB_FOLDER,
      NB_DOC,
      NB_FIELDS,
      NB_FIELDS_SHOW,
      NB_FIELDS_CONFIRM,
      NB_FIELDS_EMPTY,
      NB_KEY,
      NB_CHAR,
      NB_USEFUL_CHAR
    )
  )
location('INDEX.csv')
)
reject limit unlimited;

DROP TABLE TMP_index;
CREATE TABLE TMP_index AS(SELECT * FROM EXT_index);
```

### Information

- Database used : OracleXE 18c
- The folder containing the csv we need to import is '**\\Station-1\mainFolder\stats**' and is situated on a remote station, different than my local computer running the database

### Problem

As said previously, this script works fine when `csvdir` is a **local path** (F:\mainFolder\stats), the csv is imported into the external table and the temp table can be created from it afterwards just fine.

- When `csvdir` is a **UNC path** the error is the following : `KUP-04027: file name check failed: INDEX.csv`
- When `csvdir` is a **network drive** mapped to the previous UNC path (**J:\** mapped to \\Station-1\mainFolder, such as `csvdir`=J:\stats) the error is the following : `KUP-04040: file INDEX.csv in CSVDIR not found`

**Both these errors occur when trying to create `TMP_index` from `EXT_index` :**

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_index AS(SELECT * FROM EXT_index)
Error report -
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
--> Either KUP-04027 or KUP-04040 here, depending on how csvdir was created <--
```

- When checking in SQL Developer, `EXT_index` is always empty, the table doesn't seem to be created properly (i.e. the `Data` tab of that table doesn't even show column names)

### Steps taken for attempted resolution

- The folder '**\\Station-1\mainFolder**' is shared with 2 users having full control over it : Everyone and User1 (my account)
- On the computer that has the database (My local computer) this '**\\Station-1\mainFolder**' is mapped to a network drive : **J:\**
- When using **J:\**, `csvdir` is created as 'J:\stats'
- When using **\\Station-1\mainFolder**, `csvdir` is created as '\\Station-1\mainFolder\stats'
- As per [this link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/asktom.search?tag=oracle-user-unable-to-access-network-locations-or-permission-issues) both services `TNSListener` and `OracleServiceXE` are started logging in to my account, **User1**

### Question

**How can I import a csv file situated on a remote server into a local external table?**